# How to adapt an Sbt Logger to a PrintStream

Tags: scala, logging, io, sbt

I'm writing an Sbt plugin and I need to call some api that require a `PrintStream` for loggin the output. There is a way to adapt an sbt `Logger` (taken from `streams.value.log`) to a PrintStream that use for example the error level of the Logger?

Comment: in sbt.util.internal it appears there's a [LoggerWriter](https://github.com/sbt/util/blob/develop/internal/util-logging/src/main/scala/sbt/internal/util/LoggerWriter.scala#L12) used in [LogWriterTest](https://github.com/sbt/util/blob/develop/internal/util-logging/src/test/scala/LogWriterTest.scala#L23).  Perhaps you can use that and adapt it to a PrintStream.

Comment: @jq170727 that worked, thanks! please write it again as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I didn't want to post it as an answer because I didn't actually try it out myself but I'm glad that worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sbt.util.internal` it appears there's a [LoggerWriter](https://github.com/sbt/util/blob/develop/internal/util-logging/src/main/scala/sbt/internal/util/LoggerWriter.scala#L12) used in [LogWriterTest](https://github.com/sbt/util/blob/develop/internal/util-logging/src/test/scala/LogWriterTest.scala#L23).
Perhaps you can use that and adapt it to a PrintStream.